# How to clean JVM heap memory in spark scala or pyspark

Tags: scala, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

How to clean my JVM occupied memory in spark scala streaming application. I am running streaming job which is in 60 sec interval of time. For my first six hours no issue after that, I am facing JVM heap memory issue. Is there any way programmatically I can clean my GC or JVM memory in spark scala.

In my application, I am using Dataframe, registertemptable also end of my program I am writing the result into HDFS. Presently in my application spark SQL context level, I am uncaching, like this any other way we can release the memory?

Error msg: Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.outofmemoryError: Java heap space

Thanks

Venkat

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to see if there is any thread leak in the application.
You can look at the thread dump in the application master near the executor logs.

Try to set this parameter. --conf spark.cleaner.ttl=10000.

If you are using cache I would suggest you to use persist() it in both memory and disc